# rotation of a state in Bell basis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-computer, quantum-information

Suppose I have a state in Bell basis. For example
\begin{equation} 
\rho = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\rho_{11} &0 & 0 & \rho_{14} \\
0 &\rho_{22} & \rho_{23} & 0 \\
0 &\rho_{32} & \rho_{33} & 0 \\
\rho_{41} &0 & 0 & \rho_{44} \nonumber
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
and another state as
\begin{equation} 
\rho' = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\rho'_{11} &0 & 0 & \rho'_{14} \\
0 &\rho'_{22} & \rho'_{23} & 0 \\
0 &\rho'_{32} & \rho'_{33} & 0 \\
\rho'_{41} &0 & 0 & \rho'_{44} \nonumber
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
Provided that both the state has same purity, how can I rotate $\rho$ to get $\rho'$.

Comment: Why aren't either of your example states pure? It looks like they've been hit by parity measurements. e.g. [like this circuit](http://algorithmicassertions.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22%3A%5B%5B%22H%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22X%5Et%22%5D%2C%5B%22Density2%22%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22Density2%22%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B%22e%5E-iYt%22%5D%2C%5B%22Density2%22%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22Density2%22%5D%2C%5B%5D%5D%7D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think identical purity by itself                                                                    suffices to make $\rho$ and $\rho'$ equivalent, which implies identical spectrum. Assuming this is what you are looking for and both states are known, one general approach is to diagonalize both $\rho$ and $\rho'$, then find the basis transformation from the eigenstates of one to the other. For instance, if
$$
\rho = U D U^\dagger, \;\;\;\rho' = V D V^\dagger
$$
where $D$ is diagonal and $U$, $V$ are unitary, $U^\dagger U = U U^\dagger = V^\dagger V = V V^\dagger = I$, then $W = V U^\dagger$ transforms $\rho$ to $\rho'$,
$$
\rho' \equiv V D V^\dagger = (VU^\dagger) U D U^\dagger(VU^\dagger)^\dagger = W\rho W^\dagger
$$
Recall that $U$ and $V$ have as columns the eigenvectors of $\rho$, respectively $\rho'$, and note that in your particular case the eigenvalue problem decouples nicely, so $W$ is easy to find.

Equivalently, you could solve directly for a unitary $W$ such that
$$
\rho' = W\rho W^\dagger
$$

If you are further interested in the expression of $W$ in terms of Pauli matrices, treat it as an element of the $(2\times 2)\otimes (2\times 2)$ Hilbert space of operators/matrices with trace scalar product, and take as orthonormal basis the direct products $\frac{1}{2}{\hat\sigma}_\mu \otimes {\hat\sigma}_\nu$, $\mu,\;\nu = 0,1,2,3$, ${\hat\sigma}_0 = {\hat I}$. Then $W$ expands as 
$$
W = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{\mu,\nu}{w_{\mu\nu}{\hat\sigma}_\mu \otimes {\hat\sigma}_\nu}
$$
with coefficients $w_{\mu\nu}$ given by corresponding scalar products:
$$
w_{\mu\nu} = \frac{1}{2}Tr\left({\hat\sigma}_\mu \otimes {\hat\sigma}_\nu W \right)
$$

Comment: thanks sir, it's very helpful. Can you please have a look on my another similar kind of question ? I am giving the link of my question here. It will be very helpful for me.
http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/264227/how-to-choose-proper-measurement-operator